# Route traffic through IPSec tunnel with gateway host

Tags: iptables, ipsec, ip-forwarding

Considering the [strongswan wiki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling), this appears to be a standard problem, but I can't get it working quite right.

##### Network layout

[image: network layout]

The local site (`client` and `gateway`) is under my control, the remote site (`remote gateway` and `remote server`) is not. The IPSec tunnel is a **split tunnel** such that only requests to the `10.10.0.0/16` subnet are sent through the IPSec tunnel.

##### Goal

I would like the `client` to communicate with the `remote server`, e.g. create a `ssh` or a `smb` connection.

##### What I already did

- I've established an IPSec tunnel between the `gateway` and the `remote gateway`.
- I've enabled ip forwarding on the `gateway`:

  ```
  sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```
- I've created a NAT on the `gateway`:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
  ```
- On the `client` I've routed the traffic through the `gateway`:

  ```sh
  ip route del default
  ip route add default via 192.168.144.4
                         # 192.168.144.4 is the gateway
  ```

##### What does work

- The IPSec tunnel is established and stable.
- When logged-in into the `gateway`, I can `ping` the `remote gateway` and the `remote server` successfully. I can also `ping` the `client`. And I can `ping google.com`.
- When logged-in into the `client`, I can `ping google.com` and I can `ping` the `gateway`. With `tcpdump icmp` on the `gateway` I see that the `ping google.com` from the `client` is going through the `gateway`.

##### What does not work, yet

I cannot `ping` the `remote server` from the `client` by its IP.

```
client$ ping -c 1 10.10.12.7
PING 10.10.12.7 (10.10.12.7): 56 data bytes

--- 10.10.12.7 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

From the `tcpdump` on the `gateway`, it looks like the `ping` is sent, but not forwarded through the tunnel:

```
gateway$ tcpdump icmp
13:19:18.122999 IP 192.168.144.7 > 10.10.12.7: ICMP echo request, id 15, seq 0, length 64
13:19:18.123038 IP gateway > 10.10.12.7: ICMP echo request, id 15, seq 0, length 64
13:19:18.127534 IP ac5.nue3.m-online.net > gateway: ICMP net 10.10.12.7 unreachable, length 36
13:19:18.127556 IP ac5.nue3.m-online.net > 192.168.144.7: ICMP net 10.10.12.7 unreachable, length 36
```

As `ac5.nue3.m-online.net` is the internet-service provider of the local site, I think the packet is not routed through the IPSec tunnel, but through the internet connection of the `gateway`, which, of course, can't reach the `remote server`. (If I make the IPSec tunnel a full tunnel rather than a split tunnel, I get the same result.)

Any help or insight would be really appreciated!

##### EDIT: `ipsec statusall` on the `gateway`

```
gateway > ipsec statusall
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.8.2, Linux 5.4.0-88-generic, x86_64):
  uptime: 7 minutes, since Oct 08 08:18:24 2021
  malloc: sbrk 3112960, mmap 0, used 1081456, free 2031504
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 4
  loaded plugins: charon test-vectors ldap pkcs11 tpm aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 rdrand random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl gcrypt af-alg fips-prf gmp curve25519 agent chapoly xcbc cmac hmac ctr ccm gcm ntru drbg curl attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark farp stroke updown eap-identity eap-aka eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap eap-tnc xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam tnc-tnccs dhcp lookip error-notify certexpire led addrblock unity counters
Listening IP addresses:
  192.168.144.4
Connections:
example-ipsec:  %any...vpn1.example.com  IKEv2, dpddelay=300s
example-ipsec:   local:  [example@example.com] uses pre-shared key authentication
example-ipsec:   remote: [example@example.com] uses pre-shared key authentication
example-ipsec:   child:  dynamic === 0.0.0.0/0 TUNNEL, dpdaction=clear
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
example-ipsec[1]: ESTABLISHED 7 minutes ago, 192.168.144.4[example@example.com]...<public-ip-of-the-remote-gateway>[example@example.com]
example-ipsec[1]: I: 9d7c74f670bbda86_i* c12b3b4a236b7018_r, pre-shared key reauthentication in 2 hours
example-ipsec[1]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
example-ipsec{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: cf66ad72_i af3c9348_o
example-ipsec{1}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128, 442 bytes_i (4 pkts, 434s ago), 485 bytes_o (6 pkts, 433s ago), rekeying in 38 minutes
example-ipsec{1}:   10.10.102.235/32 === 0.0.0.0/0
```

This is the output of `ipsec statusall` on the `gateway` after unsuccessfully sending the `ping` from `client` to the `remote server`. The `ping` from the `gateway` does not change the "bytes" in the output. The "bytes" in the output correspond to a `ping` I've sent from the `gateway` to the `remote server`.

##### EDIT: `/etc/ipsec.conf` on `gateway`:

```
# /etc/ipsec.conf

conn example-ipsec
  left = %defaultroute
  leftsourceip = %config
  leftid = "example@example.com"
  right = vpn1.example.com
  rightid = "example@example.com"
  rightsubnet = 0.0.0.0/0
  leftfirewall = yes
  installpolicy = yes
  keyexchange = ikev2
  type = tunnel
  auto = start
  leftauth = psk
  rightauth = psk
  dpdaction = clear
  dpddelay = 300s
```

Comment: What's the negotiated local traffic selector for `gateway`? (i.e. post the status output of strongSwan, either `ipsec statusall` or `swanctl -l`)

Comment: Thanks @ecdsa, I've posted the output of `ipsec statusall`.

Comment: Oh, I think you might be on to something! If the last line of the `ipsec statusall` output is also a traffic selector, it might not match my NAT. But actually, I don't know where this range `10.10.102.235/32` is coming from, because it's not from my own configuration. Maybe, this is a selector imposed by the remote gateway :/

Comment: That's it @ecdsa, I've added `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.102.235; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT` (adopted from https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/2355) and then it works! Would you care to write a proper answer?

Comment: Looks like you have traffic selector misconfigured indeed. Add some configs relating to this.

Comment: Thank you, @drookie, I've added my `/etc/ipsec.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the connection uses a virtual IP address (`leftsourceip=%config`, which results in `10.10.102.235/32` as local traffic selector), you have to NAT traffic to that address, not the host's physical one you get via `MASQUERADE`, in order to match the IPsec policies and tunnel the traffic (`-I` to insert it at the top):

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING  -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.102.235
```

If the virtual IP is not statically assigned (e.g. based on the client's identity) and might change, you could install/delete the SNAT rule dynamically in a [custom updown script](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/updown) (configured via `leftupdown`) to which the virtual IP is passed in `$PLUTO_MY_SOURCEIP`.

As you originally said that this is to be a split-tunneling setup (which the remote traffic selector of `0.0.0.0/0` does not actually reflect), you could also add e.g. `-d 10.10.0.0/16` to the SNAT rule to only process packets to that subnet, other traffic would not get natted and tunneled (you can keep the `MASQUERADE` rule for that traffic). This could also be enforced via IPsec policy (`rightsubnet=10.10.0.0/16`), which you then get in `$PLUTO_PEER_CLIENT` in the updown script.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help and for this great answer, which not only shows what to do, but also why one needs to do it!